# Словообразование. Способы словообразования

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Язык постоянно пополняется новыми словами, которые образуются разными способами.

Какое из данных слов образовано иначе, чем остальные?

1)гадальщица

2)гладильщица

3)гардеробщица

4)вышивальщица

5)вязальщица

( думаю, что гардеробщица)

Comment: Проверьте мой вариант. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение верное.

1) Гардерб - гардероб/щик - гардероб/щиц/а. Существительное  "гардеробщик" мотивировано существительным, суффикс ЩИК.

2) Гадать - гада/ль/щик - гадаль/щиц/а и т.д. Существительные "гадальщик" и др. мотивированы глаголами, сложный суффикс ЛЬЩИК

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.